# Callback's flaws

Tags: c++, qt, callback

From: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html

> Callbacks have two fundamental flaws:
>   Firstly, they are not type-safe. We
>   can never be certain that the
>   processing function will call the
>   callback with the correct arguments.

Can someone explain me, in what kind of situations it is not certain that the arguments won't be correct? What is the technical gist of that statement?

**EDIT 1**
As pointed out by **Gui13** in the below post, the QString does give an error, when a char* is passed instead. But I tested the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int (*callback_function)( QString *string);

int MyCallback( std::string string )
{
    if (string.empty() == false)
        std :: cout << string.length();
    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    /* in another function */
    char *badQstring = (char*)"Booohhh";
    MyCallback( (std::string )badQstring ); 
}
```

It works properly. Does this mean that Qt's has some problems w.r.t callbacks and this does not imply that the flaw mentioned above is in plain C++ too or I am barking at the wrong tree?

Comment: @Heiko I deliberately didn't label it qt because callbacks can be implemented in either C/C++/Java etc., they are not qt specific.

Comment: Anisha you are referencing the Qt manual, which makes some assumptions about semantics that may not be true in every language used.

Comment: @Heiko I didn't understand what technically you wanted to say with "assumptions about semantics". Please explain in a layman's language. Qt uses signals and slots because callbacks have some flaws? Isn't it?

Comment: I wanted to say that a callback in Java in general is typesafe, as Java in general is typesafe. ( Of course you can negate that by only putting 'Object' as the expected types everywhere). So if the callback is 'process(String command, int times)' the types of the objects/values passed are known.

Comment: @Heiko Thanks, I have understood your quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, say Qt wants you to give him a callback that takes a pointer to a QString as its argument: your C++ typedef for the call back will look like:

```
typedef int (*callback_function)( QString *string);
```

Now, when this callback is called, you can never be sure that the argument passed is really a QString: in C++, this statement is valid and will very likely crash your callback:

```
int MyCallback( QString *string )
{
   if(string)
       printf("QString value: %s\n", string->toAscii());
}

/* in another function */
char *badQstring = "Booohhh";
MyCallback( (QString *)badQstring ); // crash, badQstring is not a QString!
```

Since C++ allows casting, you can never be sure of what type is actually passed to your callback.
But, well, this statement is valid to whatever function, even if not a callback.

Comment: thanks, to you, that program you showed does give an error "Illegal instruction", but please see the edit in first post, it is working fine with normal char* and std::string. Is the problem related to Qt specifically?

Comment: That's because you're passing a complete type (std::string) and not a pointer to it (std::string *). The cast here asct like a constructor: it's equivalent to `MyCallback( std::string(badQstring))` which is valid. Try with an `std::string *` cast instead :-)

Comment: Now I've fully understood what you've saying :) The typecast of char* to string class would be crazy since string is a class and its objects cannot be typecasted as we do in C.

Answer (score 3):

Please look at [`sqlite3_exec()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) as a good example. It's `void*` parameter is a pointer to a "context object" that is passed into the callback function when the latter is called. It's totally up to the user to be sure that this `void*` points to a type he expects.

For example, you need some complex class as a "context object". You pass an address of an object of that class into `sqlite3_exec()` and it's implicitly converted into `void*`, then when your callback is called you have to cast it back from `void*` and noone catches you if you cast it to the wrong type.

Comment: Ah, so you mean to say, that a void pointer can be passed as an function pointer argument, and that can be misused? I understand now, but isn't the case same with every function then?

Comment: @Anisha Kaul: Well, yes, but here they emphasis that the callback is designed in such way it can be passed anything because it is meant to be generic enough and you usually don't make functions that just accept whatever (like `void*`).

Answer (score 0):

It's a pointer to a function, and some compilers don't check that in run time there won't be a case where that pointer leads to a function with different parameters than expected.