# Type-safety in callbacks

Tags: c++, callback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Callback’s flaws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829483/callbacks-flaws)

I have read in the Qt docs that:

> Callbacks have two fundamental flaws: Firstly, they are not type-safe.
>   We can never be certain that the processing function will call the
>   callback with the correct arguments.

I am not sure why we can't be certain about the correctness of the arguments for callback. Aren't they type-safe because in such example wich I have written:

```
void callback( int a ) {
    printf( "something" );
}

void ourProcessingFunc( void ( *cb )( int ) ) {
    cb( 'a' );
}

int main() {
    ourProcessingFunc( callback );

    return 0;
}
```

we can pass to the callback (in ourProcessingFunc) arguments other than int? For example char or long etc.? Or they are not type-safe because of something else? Sorry for the idiotic question, I'd like to be sure.

Comment: yeah, sorry, but is my example good too? for showing that the callbacks are not type-safe?

Comment: What you are using is an implicit cast, the other question uses explicit casts.. perhaps explicit casts are more relevant as an example. but frankly im not clear myself on why this affects only callbacks.. any place that can typecast is effectively not typesafe..

Comment: @KarthikT - there's no such thing as an "implicit cast". A **cast** is something you write in your code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. There are implicit **conversions** and explicit **conversions**.